# How do I stop services from starting on boot on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, apache-http-server, mysql

I have lots of servers installed (Apache, MySQL, etc.), but I don't want them all to start at boot time (they drain power, and I'm on batteries most of the time). How do I configure this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In the console, you could write:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
sudo update-rc.d -f mysql remove
...
```

For additional information read *[Ubuntu Bootup How to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto)*.

Answer (score 11):

Things have changed quite a bit in Ubuntu now. I think from version 11 onwards.
MySQL is handled by **Upstart** while Apache still uses traditional **SysV init** scripts

For MySQL, you can use the new override feature in **Upstart** to modify the starting behaviour:

`sudo echo "manual" >> /etc/init/mysql.override`

For more info, see the section "[Disabling a Job from Automatically Starting](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting)" in the Upstart Cookbook.

As Apache still uses the traditional **SysV init** scripts you can use

`sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove`

to remove the links from `/etc/rcX.d` or, alternatively use

`sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable`

which "disables" the script by changing it from a start script to a stop script. This is reversible by

`sudo update-rc.d apache2 enable`

---

*Most of this information I got from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/40077/24678*

Comment: I get "bash: /etc/init/mysql.override: Permission denied" when run "sudo echo "manual" >> /etc/init/mysql.override" in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @HungTran - As superuser, try creating the file /etc/init/mysql.override with an editor - with contents containing the word manual

Answer (score 5):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20061110174157/https://help.ubuntu.com/6.10/ubuntu/desktopguide/C/ch10s06.html) link is a bit out dated version wise, but does it match an option in your version?

> **Configure startup services**
>
> This requires administrative
>   privileges (see Chapter 2,
>   Administrative Tasks).
>
> 1. Run Services Settings: **System** → **Administration** → **Services**.
> 2. Enter your password.
> 3. Select the services you want running, then click **OK** when done.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Boot-Up Manager](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bum.html) for start and stop boot-up scripts, without the necessity to handle thru complex links and permissions.

```
apt-get install bum
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way to accomplish this is to 'disable' the sym link - not delete it.

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql disable 2
```

This will rename the sym link to start with 'K' and the service won't start-up on boot. You can then re-enable it at any time if you do decide you want it to start-up on boot.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16:

```
 sudo systemctl disable mysql
```

`update-rc.d` method wasn't working for me.

Upstart has been deprecated in Ubuntu 15.